# How to find the location of latex installation for use with sphinx?

Tags: command-line, latex

I am using sphinx to build documentation for a python project; and the documentation includes mathematical notation to be executed by Latex.  I know that I need to specify the location of Latex on my (linux system) computer when I build the docs from the command line, something along the lines of the following example given by the sphinx documentation:

```
sphinx-build -b html -D imgmath_latex=C:\tex\latex.exe . _build/html
```

I have just installed latex using the command `sudo apt-get install texlive`

How do I find out where Latex was installed and how do I use that in my build command?

When I try the command `dpkg -l texlive`  the output is

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                            Version                      Architecture                 Description
+++-===============================================-============================-============================-===================================================================================================
ii  texlive                                         2016.20160819-2                 all                          TeX Live: A decent selection of the TeX Live packages
```

Comment: Have you tried not setting it at all? I suspect it's only necessary to set it explicitly if `latex` is not in the current executable search path - *nix systems are usually quite smart about things like this

Comment: Okay yeah thanks it works fine without setting it.

Answer (score 1):

One way to find out where the latex executable is installed is

```
which latex
```

Comment: For example results of `which latex` in 18.04 are `/usr/bin/latex`